# Upload data in BigQuery in the order in which it is in the original data and not in some sorted manner

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to get data uploaded in bigquery in the order in which it is in the original data ? As, when I am uploading data into bigquery, its getting sorted. I do not want this sorting and want the data to be in the original order. What can I do for that?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. BigQuery does its own indexing and compression for query optimization, so that's probably what that sorting is all about

Comment: I have an entire dataset as a csv . I need to do some processing in a few columns of the csv using bigquery. What can I do to restore the order when I am replacing the old columns with the processed ones?

Comment: I recommend you to ask yourself few questions. like - 1) what kind of processing in BigQuery that you need to do and why in BigQuery? 2) why exactly you need to restore the order? Most likely you will do then something else? what it is? and so on...You would be surprised in how many cases answering such questions changes whole thing! At the same time if you share more details with us - it will help us to help you more effectively than just answering probably not the best question you could ask for your problem. :o)

Comment: Thank you for for suggestions :) I am actually applying machine learning to the data set which is serving as my training data. Before applying machine learning, I need to perform certain pre-processing steps like converting categories to numbers in the columns of my csv where the data type of the column is string. This part of my code I am implementing using BigQuery.So, I am creating a schema of the columns with string data type and one by one trying to process them through a query and the restore that processed column back to the csv and then apply machine learning algo to it.

Comment: That is the reason I want the order to be restored as I want to replace that processed column with the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables in BigQuery don't have any fixed order, and `SELECT * FROM table` query may return rows in different order every time it runs. The only way to be able to control order of rows, is by adding some ordering column (timestamp or just sequential number), that you will be able to use in `ORDER BY` clause later.

Answer (score 1):

One way to upload a dataset and keep its original sort is to assign an index column before uploading, and then use the
`ORDER BY` clause when querying from BigQuery.

Please see example for Python below:

1. Assign Index Column to DF

   - `sampleDf['idx'] = [i+1 for i in range(len(sampleDf))]`
2. Upload Dataset to BigQuery
3. Use `ORDER BY` clause when querying dataset.

   - `SELECT * FROM project.dataset.table ORDER BY idx ASC;`

I've ran into this issue where BigQuery sorts uploaded tables. Hope this helps.