# Why is my column order in my table schema not respected by the pandas.to_gbq function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I want to upload a panda dataframe to Big Query using the [Dataframe.to_gbq()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html) function.

I specify a table_schema argument to force a specific column order in BigQuery (that might differ from Dataframe).

So I use for example :

```
table_schema = [{'name': 'col1', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
{'name': 'col2', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
{'name': 'col3', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
{'name': 'col4', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
{'name': 'col5', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
{'name': 'col6', 'type': 'FLOAT64'}, 
{'name': 'col7', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
{'name': 'col8', 'type': 'FLOAT64'}]

Dataframe.to_gbq(destination_table, if_exists='replace', table_schema=table_schema)
```

Colum order in Dataframe is :
Col1, Col3,Col4, Col5, Col2, Col6, Col7,Col8

Job is done correctly.

But then when I check table schema of the created (or replaced) destination_table in Big Query, column order is :
Col1, Col3,Col4, Col5, Col2, Col6, Col7,Col8

(order of the dataframe and not that of the table_schema)

Shouldn't the order specified in the table schema be respected ?

If not, is there a way to force that ?

Comment: Someone answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848567/upload-data-in-bigquery-in-the-order-in-which-it-is-in-the-original-data-and-not)

Comment: @KaBoom Column ordering is different from row ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Reorder the columns of the dataframe by indexing it in the order you want

```py
ordered_columns = [c['name'] for c in table_schema]

Dataframe[ordered_columns].to_gbq(destination_table, if_exists='replace', table_schema=table_schema)
```

Comment: Ok it works ! I really thought order of the dicts for each column in the table schema was important but in fact in does not : the order of the columns in the dataframe remains unmodified. THANKS !!